# Replacing the inner.html of an unknown named element based on condition

Tags: javascript, html

I run into this problem frequently and never know the best approach. Imagine I have a structure that includes several instances of the following html:

```
<div class="known">
    <div class="another unknown">
        <div class="unknown">
            <h4>Something a something</H4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For each div of class known, I want to change the inner html of that div only if it contains a div inside it with some particular tag, in this case `<h4>`.

What is the best way to achieve that.  I know that I could do it by taking the inner html of class known and doing a regex match. But is there a more robust way based on tags?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just use a selector that spans over the `div.known` and restrict it's context to `div h4`. If the selector selects at lease one element then the `div.class` has children as you expect.

```
if( $('.known div h4').length > 0 ){
    $('.known').html('Some html');
}
```

Comment: This solution will modify all elements with class .known if at least one of them contains a div with an h4. I believe this is inaccurate - the question seeks to modify only that one div.known that contains an h4. Can use jQuery's .has() operator

Comment: `I want to change the inner html of that div only if it contains a div inside it with some particular tag, in this case <h4>.` :)

Comment: Fair enough. That is not what this solution does. Your solution will target ALL elements with class "known" if ANY one of those elements contains a div and an h4.

Comment: :D Okay. The condition is "if it contains `a div inside it with some particular tag` (h4 in this case)". This is what this script does. And yes. This is what the OP needs. ALL `div.known` elements with a div that contains h4. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can do this.

```
var head = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("h4 #known"));
for(var i = 0; i < head.length; i++)
{
    while(head[i].className !== "known")
        head[i] = head[i].parent();
}
```

Now head will be an array of all the DOM elements have the tag `known` and have `h4`'s in them.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can use .has() to narrow your selection and even chain other methods, as in:

```
$(".known").has("h4").css("background","red");
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqsinger/0fvyehk7/) for example. Notice that clicking the button will change the color of any div.known only if that element contains an h4 tag as a descendant.

Documentation on jQuery's .has() -- https://api.jquery.com/has/